# can I access google AMP pages offline?

Tags: amp-html

for example, I want to use this plugin in a AMP page:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-fit-text" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fit-text-0.1.js"></script>
```

for use that, I must connect to the internet.

Is there a way to use that plugin offline without internet?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had any success? What do error messages say?

Comment: Have you tried service workers? I think that will help and amp has his own way to implement service workers